# How can I disable the music player on an iPhone 4S lock screen

Tags: iphone, ipod-touch

How do I disable the music player controls on the iPhone 4S lock screen?
I've tried setting the "triple click home button" to "off", but it didn't help.

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid this is not possible by default on your iPhone. It's a feature in iOS and there is no easy way to disable this.

You could jailbreak your iPhone, you can buy [Springtomize](http://www.idownloadblog.com/2011/03/14/springtomize-goes-live-in-cydia-brings-extensive-customization-to-ios/) for $2,99 which will allow you to do what you want. Just turn on the "Hide Top Bar" option.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

On a iPhone 6, hold the right side button and the home button for at least 10 seconds, until the apple logo appears. When the phone restarts it should be gone.

Comment: Just like questions, the quality of answers matter. Please edit your answer and explain why it is better and correct over the rest. We are looking for more than just two sentences here.

Answer (score 0):

On my iphone se I held the home button and the start button at the top of phone, the phone turned off, and when it restarted it was gone