# iPhone - How to turn off the music widget (on the lock screen)?

Tags: iphone, music.app

How to close the music widget thing (see screenshot below) on the lock screen?

So:

- make it stop playing music (and wasting battery*)
- make it disappear from the lock screen

It can not be swiped to the left (or right) as other objects on the lock screen.

* once it got activated somehow, played music for an hour or two (I did not hear it as I have volume set to zero most of the time) and the the battery died (was empty)

This old question looks like a duplicate, but it is very concise, also the answers don't look very useful: [How can I disable the music player on an iPhone 4S lock screen](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/52110/how-can-i-disable-the-music-player-on-an-iphone-4s-lock-screen)

[image]

PS: I know that stopping it from playing can be done with the play/pause button. I listed this requirement to avoid answers that make the widget go away, but the music continues to play.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swipe halfway up to open the app switcher, then swipe up the app that was playing music ( apple music probably, because the other apps get terminated by the OS pretty quickly ), that will force close the music app and stop showing the controls in the lock screen.

Comment: With "swipe up to the app" you mean "swipe up the app", right? I was already using this solution/workaround, but hoped for a more elegant one. Will accept shortly if no better answer is posted.

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant, I will edit the answer thanks.